# How do you manipulate the data of a gridview object in Visual Basic? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

What is the syntax for elements of a gridview object?

I want to be able to manipulate a gridview object in Visual Studio 2010 as if it were a two dimensional array where each individual element of this array contains a variable.

How could I do something like:

```
GridView1.SetElementAt(X,Y) = strEventName
```

where X is the row index and Y is the column index.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Rows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows.aspx) and the [Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells.aspx) properties:

```
GridView1.Rows(X).Cells(Y).Text = strEventName
```

Comment: I think I have to initialize the GridView object, I tried adding "test" to position 0,0 but I received the "Index was out of range." error. How do I initialize an empty 4x4 gridView object?

Comment: The Rows and Cells properties have Add methods.  Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells.aspx

Comment: That only applies to Table objects. I'm required to use GridView objects for my assignment.